# how to convert multiple columns into rows

Tags: mysql

I have Data Table like this

| Id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | abc | bca | def |
| 002 | efg | abc | ghi |
| 003 | bca | xyz | def |

how to be like this

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | abc |
| 001 | bca |
| 001 | def |
| 002 | efg |
| 002 | abc |
| 002 | ghi |
| 003 | bca |
| 003 | xyz |
| 003 | def |

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more control, I would recommend using a cursor in a stored procedure. But if you just want to achieve your expected output, Akina's suggestion is quite straightforward.

```
select id , a as value 
from
    (select id, a from test
    union
    select id, b from test
    union
    select id, c from test) t
order by id
; -- union does not warrant the function of ORDER BY clause in it, so we should make the union statement  a derived table and have the parent query sort it out.
```

Answer (score -2):

Converting columns to rows is called unpivoting. Converting rows to columns is pivoting.

One approach to unpivoting data is to combine the [apply operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175156(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with a [table value constructor.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)

This example uses a [common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) to return 3 sample records.

```
-- Unpivoting with apply and VALUES.        
WITH SampleData AS
    (
        /* This CTE returns 3 sample records.
         */             
        SELECT
            cte.*
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
                    (2, 'd', 'e', 'f'),
                    (3, 'g', 'h', 'i')
            ) AS cte(Id, ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, ColumnThree)
    )
SELECT
    sd.Id,
    ca.*
FROM
    SampleData AS sd
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                VALUES
                    (ColumnOne),
                    (ColumnTwo),
                    (ColumnThree)
            ) AS ca (ColumnFour)
;
```

Comment: The question is tagged as MySQL-related. Your code is SQL Server-specific.

Comment: Sorry, may I ask for a demo example, so I can understand

Comment: sorry. this is for sql server or mysql